# How to add an id to Listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a listview within an activity and at the bottom of the screen I have a scrollable gallery, my problem is making the listview clickable, I would normally use the listview position by doing if(position == 3) and then create the intent but postion is being used by my gallery.

I listview is in the main.xml populated by an array.xml, can I add an id i.e android:id in the arrays.xml and create an intent with that, or can I create a listactivity and still use position to fire an intent if so how would I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this thread will give you some idea on how to solve your problem.
http://groups.google.is/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/da8081f997d919ce

other supporting links which can help you grab idea on the List View are :
[More about Listviews_developerlife.com](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327)
[android-custom-listview-tutorial-example-part-1](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/)
[android-custom-listview-tutorial-example-part-2](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example-part-2/)

Thanks,
Sen